# JRE version in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

How can I tell what version of Java (JRE) my ColdFusion 11 is running? Is there somewhere in the CF administrator that can tell me if it's version 1.7 or 1.8?

Comment: CF Administrator -> SERVER SETTINGS -> Settings Summary -> JVM Details.

Comment: @RRK - If this wasn't already asked and answered in the archives, you should've posted that as an answer :-)

Comment: @Ageax this one is not really a question imo. That is why I was reluctant to do so. ;-)

Comment: @RRK - Heh. Agreed it is not about cfml code per se, but is likely something most CF devs would need to know at some point. Seems easy now, but at some point I didn't know the answer.  Since quick searching didn't return anything CF specific on S.O, imho it's probably a good reference thread to have in the archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of ColdFusion, go to the CFAdmin, click on the information icon (top right of window) - or click on "Settings Summary" in the left menu (both links lead to the same page). On that page under System Information is a sub heading called JVM Details. Under that you'll find what you're looking for in the Java Version.